# json в python не может дампить словарь с ключами являющимися байтами. Как обойти?

Tags: python, json, pyaudio

У меня есть аудио данные, полученные с помощью pyaudio. К ним я применяю алгоритм хаффмана и получаю на выходе закодированные данные и словарь для декодирования. Это дело мне надо передать по сети, поэтому я использую json, который не работает с моим словарём, где ключами являются байты. Вот небольшой кусок словаря для наглядности:

```
{b'\x00': '00', b'\xea': '01000000', b'b': '010000010', b'"': '010000011', b'\xbc': '010000100'}
```

Я попробовал представить ключи в виде десятичных, а потом преобразовать их обратно:

```
            #работа алгоритма хаффмана
            encodeStr, symbolCode = HF.encode(sound)
            newDict = {}
            #преобразую ключи словаря в десятичные
            for key in symbolCode:
                newDict[ord(key)] = symbolCode[key]
            print('symbolCode: ', symbolCode)
            DD = {}
            # Преобразую ключи словаря в двоичные
            for key in newDict:
                DD[hex(key).encode()] = newDict[key]
            print('DD: ', DD)
```

В итоге вышло так что словарь DD не похож на изначальный symbolCode. Вот фрагмент:

```
symbolCode:  {b'\x00': '00', b'\xea': '01000000', b'b': '010000010', b'"': '010000011'}
DD:  {b'0x0': '00', b'0xea': '01000000', b'0x62': '010000010', b'0x22': '010000011'}
```

Больше мне никаких вариантов решения проблемы в голову не пришло.

Comment: Так как у Вас каждый ключ это ровно 1 байт, то вместо типа `bytes` можно использовать значение этого байта, т.е. `int`.

Comment: Кстати, не обязательно использовать `json` для передачи по сети. Можете использовать модуль `pickle` для сериализации любых **built-in** типов в `bytes`.

Comment: Спасибо, pickle мне помог!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у Вас каждый ключ это ровно 1 байт, то вместо типа `bytes` можно использовать значение этого байта, т.е. `int`, а на принимающей стороне, если необходимо, конвертировать этот `int` в `bytes`.

---

Перевод из `bytes` в `int`:

```py
integer = int.from_bytes(b"\xea", "big")
# Т.к. байт всего один, то не имеет разницы, big или little
```

---

Конвертация `int` в `bytes`:

```py
byte = integer.to_bytes(1, "big")
# Аналогично
```

---

Но использовать `json` для передачи по сети не обязательно. Советую воспользоваться модулем `pickle`, который умеет сериализовывать любые **built-in** типы в `bytes` и обратно.

```py
import pickle
symbolCode = {b'\x00': '00', b'\xea': '01000000', b'b': '010000010', b'"': '010000011', b'\xbc': '010000100'}

encoded = pickle.dumps(symbolCode) # Кодируем в байты

print(type(encoded), len(encoded), encoded, sep=" | ")
# <class 'bytes'> | 105 | b'\x80\x03}q\x00(C\x01\x00q\x01X\x02\x00\x00\x0000q\x02C\x01\xeaq\x03X\x08\x00\x00\x0001000000q\x04C\x01bq\x05X\t\x00\x00\x00010000010q\x06C\x01"q\x07X\t\x00\x00\x00010000011q\x08C\x01\xbcq\tX\t\x00\x00\x00010000100q\nu.'

decoded = pickle.loads(encoded) # Восстанавливаем словарь обратно

print(decoded == symbolCode)
# True
```